# copy data from table in different database

Tags: sql

I have two databases : DataB1 with table1 and DataB2 with Table2

```
Table1 has : field1, field2, filed3
Table2 has : fielda, fieldb, fieldc
```

Different fields name but same data type.

Question : How can I do a stored procedure that opens databases and copies from table1 to table2?

Comment: Which databases? Can you not simply use a database link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an insert.  In most databases, it would look like:

```
insert into datab1.table1(field1, field2, field3)
    select fielda, fieldb, fieldc
    from datab2.table2;
```

Some databases might have a three part naming convention if the schema name is also involved.

EDIT:

With a three-part naming convention, it might be something like:

```
insert into datab1.dbo.table1(field1, field2, field3)
    select fielda, fieldb, fieldc
    from datab2.dbo.table2;
```

Comment: How would be if schema is involved?

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your database server, but most have `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO
    DataB2.Table2 (fielda,fieldb,fieldc)
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM DataB1.Table1
```

A better alternative is probably a `VIEW`, if you just want to easily see the data from another database.

```
CREATE VIEW
    DataB2.View2
AS SELECT
    field1 AS fielda,
    field2 AS fieldb,
    field3 AS fieldc
FROM DataB1.Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a stored procedure, but it's much earlier. In SSMS, right click source database node, select Tasks -> export data. See more at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: This only works on Microsoft SQL Server and is not really an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Each database has its own methods to do it.
For example in Firebird 2.5 you can do the same thing:

```
execute block
returns(ID_N Integer, ID_R Integer)
as
begin
  For
    select ID from TABLE into :ID_N
  Do
  Begin
    ID_R=0;
    execute statement 'select ID from TABLE where ID='||:ID_N
      on external data source 'Path_to_remote_database'
      as user current_user password 'user_password'
      into :ID_R;
    if (:ID_R>0) then
      suspend;
  End
end;
```

This code shows matching ID's from two tables. So using "execute statement on external data source" you can do everything you need.